# Find string while knowing part of it and return string

Tags: bash, shell-script, grep

I have a string, for example

```
"Icecream123 AirplaneBCD CompanyTL1 ComputerYU1"
```

Let's say I know that my string will contain for sure the substring IceCream but I don't know what follows it.

It might be 123 as in my example or it might be something different.

While I can use grep to detect if "Icecream" substring exists in my string with the following command

```
echo $string | grep -oF 'Icecream';
```

Which will print

```
Icecream
```

I want with a command to get it to print the whole substring, which in my example is

```
Icecream123
```

Of course what follows Icecream is random and not known beforehand so I can't just do

```
$SUBSTRING=$(echo $string | grep -oF 'Icecream')
$SUBSTRINGTRAIL=123
echo $SUBSTRING$SUBSTRINGTRAIL
```

Comment: is the substring fixed / static -- always "Icecream", or is it variable?

Comment: will a space indicate the end of the desired suffix?

Comment: @JeffSchaller Sadly, I don't know that. I am actually getting a multiline output from another command, which I store in a variable, this variable is my $string, when it get's echoed it displays the multiline output as a signle line with a space between them. I don't actually know if that's a space or a special character such as LF. I thought that it's space.

Comment: I mean, for example, `Icecream123 AirplaneBCD` you want stopped at `123`. Is that because there's a space after the 3, or something else?

Comment: $string is populated by a multiline output, when it's echoed it displays this multiline output as a single line with a space between the lines. Now I don't know if that space is actually a space or the NewLine character which is console it shows up as a space. I hope this makes more sense.

Comment: If you're not sure what your data is, it's hard to write an appropriate solution. All the answers so far are assuming your data is on one line, like you've shown it. I was trying to figure out what your delimiter was -- where the "trailing" part should stop.

Comment: @JeffSchaller I undestand that, and I actually remembered it when I've read your comment. If you refresh the page you will see that I have already picked up a solution as echo "$string" | grep -oP 'Icecream.*?\b' and 'Icecream\S+' are working :) Thanks for your time

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If your `grep` supports perl compatible regular expressions, you could match non-greedily up to the next word boundary:

```
echo "$string" | grep -oP 'Icecream.*?\b'
```

Otherwise, match the longest sequence of non-blank characters:

```
echo "$string" | grep -o 'Icecream[^[:blank:]]*'
```

Or keep everything in the shell and remove the longest trailing sequence of characters starting with a space:

```
echo "${string%% *}"
```

Comment: For the PCRE, I'd use `'Icecream\S+'` for some non-blank characters.

Comment: Thanks for your comments, saddly it seems that my version of grep does not support perl regex. 

Could you add some more details about your third option? I am not quite sure how to implement it.

Comment: After some more testing it seems that using either echo "$string" | grep -oP 'Icecream.*?\b' or 'Icecream\S+' it does the job. Thanks

Comment: it's really confusing that although your $string variable is a string you still have to put it between double quotes!

Comment: @Sonamor in this case the quoting is not strictly necessary; however there are so many cases where it *is* that it's a good habit to get into. See for example [When is double-quoting necessary?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/68748/65304)

Comment: @Sonamor You absolutely need to learn about quoting! It's the most important to know, I think. The point is that many problems with quoting are like that: confusing. Works first, but  not with other input.

Answer (score 8):

Since you tagged bash:

```
[[ $string =~ (Icecream[^ ]*) ]] && result=${BASH_REMATCH[1]}
```

More generally, for a search term in `$search`:

```
[[ $string =~ ($search[^ ]*) ]] && result=${BASH_REMATCH[1]}
```

... or with parameter expansion:

```
# remove any leading text up to -and through- the search text:
x=${string##*$search}

# remove any trailing space onwards
result=$search${x%% *}
```

Answer (score 7):

Using a `grep` that knows about `-o`:

```
$ printf '%s\n' "$string" | grep -o '\<Icecream[^[:blank:]]*'
Icecream123
```

The pattern `\<Icecream[^[:blank:]]*` matches the string `Icecream` (where the `I` is preceded by a non-word character, or the start of the line) followed by zero or more non-blanks (not spaces or tabs).

---

Using `awk`:

```
$ printf '%s\n' "$string" | awk -v RS=' ' '/^Icecream/'       
Icecream123
```

The `awk` program divides the string into space-separated records, and tests each one.  It will print the ones that start with the string `Icecream`.

Using `mawk` or GNU `awk`, you may also use

```
printf '%s\n' "$string" | awk -v RS='[[:blank:]]' '/^Icecream/'
```

since they interpet `RS` as a regular expression if it contains more than one character.

---

With `sed`, in a similar fashion as with `grep`:

```
$ printf '%s\n' "$string" | sed 's/.*\(\<Icecream[^[:blank:]]*\).*/\1/'
Icecream123
```

---

Using `/bin/sh`:

```
set -- Icecream123 AirplaneBCD CompanyTL1 ComputerYU1
for string; do
    case $string in
        Icecream*)
            printf '%s\n' "$string"
            break
    esac
done
```

---

Perl (with a little help from `tr`):

```
$ printf '%s\n' "$string" | tr ' ' '\n' | perl -ne '/Icecream\S*/ && print'
Icecream123
```

or just

```
$ printf '%s\n' "$string" | perl -ne '/(Icecream\S*)/ && print $1, "\n"'
Icecream123
```

Comment: Or, split into lines and match the key: `echo "$string" | grep -o '\S\+' | grep "Icecream"`

Answer (score 2):

For example, if you use `GNU grep`:

```
$ echo "Icecream123 AirplaneBCD CompanyTL1 ComputerYU1" | grep -oP '\bIcecream.*?(\s|$)' --color
```

It uses `PCRE`.

Answer (score 1):

A little bit simpler perhaps, especially since you say that your version of grep does not support perl regex:

`$ echo $string | tr ' ' '\n' | grep 'Icecream'
Icecream123`

The `tr` splits the string into lines by replacing all the spaces with newlines. Then you can use `grep` easily.

You can also write the following to obtain only what follows the word you are looking for:

`$ echo $string | tr ' ' '\n' | sed -n 's/Icecream//p'
123`